# How to get last random int generated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I'm writing some code to find patterns in pseudo-random numbers. I would like to print these numbers as they are added to a list. How do I get the last generated 'random' int? I would use this value to print it to the console.
I've looked through the documentation, but can't find that in the documentation.

Here is some code:

```py
pseudo_random_list += str(random.randrange(0, 9))
# [Snippet to print last integer generated]
```

(`pseudo_random_list` is a string.)

I would also not like to creat temp variables. (Memory isn't unlimited)

Comment: What do you mean "last" generated int? You need to be more specific.

Comment: If you are adding them to a list, just look at the last item in the list -- `someList[-1]`

Comment: This is not supported. You have to remember it in a variable, list or similar.

Comment: *last generated int* as in the one prior to the current step or the truly *last* one?

Comment: @AeroBlue When I generate an integer using a random module function I want to be able to find the last value I generated.

Comment: @C.Nivs I mean the truly last one.

Comment: @Divergence your question doesn't make any sense? Do you just want to print the value before it's added to the list?

Comment: @AeroBlue Printing it first or last both require a temp variable so I would like a way to access some entity in `random` that would return the **last value the random module generated**

Comment: Divergence: IMO `pseudo_random_list` is a very misleading variable name for a *string* object...

Answer (score 2):

Just assign the integer to a variable:

```
num = random.randint(1,5)

print(num)  # First time

print(num)  # Print again, to verify it doesn't change
```

And it stays the same:

```
4
4
```

Example of using this in a loop:

```
while True:
    num = random.randint(1,5)

    print(num)

    # Do whatever here
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by writing your own function that remembers the last digit it returned. Since it only stores the last one, it won't consume more and more memory every time it's called.

```
import random

def random_digit():
    random_digit.last = random.randrange(0, 9)
    return random_digit.last

pseudo_random_list = ''

for _ in range(7):
    pseudo_random_list += str(random_digit())

# Sample usage.
print(repr(pseudo_random_list)) # -> '5538304'
print(random_digit.last) # -> 4
```

**Note:** I think you may want to use [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) instead of [`random.randrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) because `random.randrange(0, 9)` will only generate numbers in the range 0..8, whereas [`random.randint(0, 9)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) would generate numbers in the range 0..9.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out myself.

I can simply add a value to my list and then print the value using `print(pseudo_random_list[-1])`

Comment: This will give you the last _character_ that was added to the list, not the last `int` generated (although there's a relationship between the two, obviously).

Comment: @martineau Practically, it is, because I added the last int to the end of the list.

Answer (score -1):

Just have a temp variable that they get passed through. That will have the last value.

Comment: Generating a bunch of numbers and then comparing two slices (as I'm doing) is very memory-intensive already, and I would not like to add creating temp variables to the mix.

Comment: @Divergence Then please add your code to your question

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. Using:
`temp = random.randrange(0, 9);`
`pseudo_random_list += str(temp)`
This would only have 1 temp variable the gets overwrote with the last random number. (Almost no increase on memory)